# Spring REST Jerkson generates array format

Tags: scala, spring-mvc, jackson, jerkson

I am using Spring MVC 3.2.2 as my REST framework.

I am using Jerkson (Scala) Jackson wrapper.

I am trying to figure out my when my rest layer returns a single object the json String contains square brackets ([]) as it was an array (although it is not).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Turned out it was a logging problem. I am using an slf4j log wrapper that wrapped the returned string as an array.